# R grep final outer set of brackets

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector:

```
vec <- c("some text (important1)", "some text, (important2 (unimportant))",
"some text", "some text (unimportant) (important3)")
```

How can I use `grep()` to extract only the `important` text, e.g.:

```
c("important1", "important2", NA, "important3")
```

Comment: First, please take a few minutes to …read the [Regex wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) and [What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) …search [the most frequently-asked Regex questions on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex?sort=frequent) …search [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for details on your specific regex engine …and use [regex101.com](https://www.regex101.com/) for explaining and debugging regexp. Then, explain your question in detail.

Comment: Regular expression questions get better answers if they… show the pattern that isn't working, provide some examples of input text that should match, **and also** ones that shouldn't match. Describe the desired results, and how the pattern isn't producing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stringr` library and functions `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(vec,paste(c("important1","important2","important3"),collapse="|"))
```

Resulting in

```
"important1" "important2" NA           "important3"
```

if you think you'll have others "important4","important5" etc etc

```
n<-10
to_match=collapse(paste("important",seq(1,n,by=1),sep=""),"|")   
str_extract(vec,to_match)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `str_extract`, also:

```
stringr::str_extract(vec, "\\bimportant\\d+")
# "important1" "important2" NA           "important3"
```